# Deploying MERN stack web app on Ubuntu server(Alibaba ECS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, deployment, alibaba-cloud

I am building a web app using MongoDB, ExpressJS, ReactJS(create-react-app) and NodeJS. I am done with the development part now I want to deploy this web app to an Ubuntu Server.

My file structures looks like this [Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmDVM.png)

**package.json (Server)**

```
{
    "name": "pair-programming",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "pair-programming web app for codechef's hackathon",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
        "start": "node server.js",
        "server": "nodemon server.js",
        "client": "npm start --prefix client",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
        "serve-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
    },
    "author": "Parmeet Singh",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
        "express": "^4.16.3",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
        "mongodb": "^3.1.6",
        "mongoose": "^5.2.13",
        "node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
        "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
        "passport": "^0.4.0",
        "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
        "request": "^2.88.0",
        "sprintf-js": "^1.1.1",
        "validator": "^10.7.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
    }
}
```

**package.json (react)**

```
{
    "name": "client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "react": "^16.5.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
        "redux": "^4.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "proxy": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
}
```

So please if possible help me deploy this web app to ubuntu server. I haven't deployed on ubuntu before.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, you need to run a couple of commands which deploys both your server and the react code successfully,

Assuming you don't have any GUI installed, we have to use something called as `screen`

1. ssh your instance via the putty/similar program. [ssh root@< ipaddress >]
2. once logged in you need to type `screen` (this will give you a seperate window to run your commands)
3. `cd` to your server directory & run `npm start` (this will start your server code)
4. Then press `CTRL-A` then `CTRL-D` this will detach the process.
5. Again type screen and then `cd` to the react directory & run `npm start`. This will make your react app to run. Then detach the process.
6. You can logout the session now/exit the terminal.

Finally, Also make sure the ports are opened for accessing via internet/Intranet.

Comment: Thank you for your kind detailed answer. I was trying to do same but the website wasn't accessible from the internet. The main issue was I didn't set up security for port 80.

Comment: Perfect!! Hope that works now :) Accept & Upvote if helped